# Nested IF In Visual Basic

Tags: vba, nested-if

I want to make a program that
"Loan will be accepted if
Earns over 30k & on the job for more than 2 years or been on the job for more than 5 years.
and age between 30 - 50.

But doesn't working

```
If sngSalary > 30000 Then
    If sngAge < 50 Then
        If sngYear > 5 Then
            lblMessage.Text = "Application qualifies"
        Else
            lblMessage.Text = "Application does not qualifies"
        End If
    Else
         If sngYear >= 2 Then
            lblMessage.Text = "Application qualifies"
         Else
            lblMessage.Text = "Application does not qualifies"
         End If
    End If
Else
    If sngAge > 30 Then
         If sngYear > 5 Then
             lblMessage.Text = "Application qualifies"
         Else
             lblMessage.Text = "Application does not qualifies"
         End If
    Else
         If sngYear >= 2 Then
             lblMessage.Text = "Application qualifies"
         Else
             lblMessage.Text = "Application does not qualifies"
         End If
    End If
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Just code it up almost exactly like you said in your description:

```
Private Sub Test()
   If (sngSalary > 30000 And sngYear > 2) Or (sngYear > 5 And sngAge >= 30 And sngAge <= 50) Then
      lblMessage.Text = "Application qualifies"
   Else
      lblMessage.Text = "Application does not qualifies"
   End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Quite often complex logic can be simplified by moving the code to a function and revising the logic so that the function is left early if a criteria is not met.  In writing such a function I try to keep the logic retricted to simple yes/no gates.

The expression of the required conditions by the OP is quite confused so the code below may not be correct, but it does demonstrate the principle.

```
Option Explicit

Public Function IsEligible(ByVal ipSalary As Long, ByVal ipAge As Long, ByVal ipEmploymentTime As Long) As String

    IsEligible = "Application does not qualify"
    If ipEmployment < 2 Then Exit Function
    
    If ipSalary < 30000
    
        If ipEmploymentTime < 5 Then Exit Function
        If ipAge < 30 Then Exit Function
        If ipAge > 50 Then Exit Function
    
    End If
    
    IsEligible = "Application qualifies"
    
End Function
```

Comment: I like this idea and use it often in my code.  One thought:  I would expect the function to return a Boolean based upon it's name.

Comment: @BrianMStafford  You are of course correct.  I changed my mind halfway through writing and didn't update the function signature.